# iOS 11 apps only from July 2018

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am making an app and I have already spoken to several people about it. They would like to download it once it is released on the app store.

I received an email and have researched into the changes which state:

> "Starting July 2018, all new iOS apps and updates submitted to the App
>   Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK."

Some of the people I have spoken to have older devices which cannot run iOS 11, and I will not be able to run it on my own phone either (I will on my iPad, however).

I therefore want to release on iOS 9, but will not be able to do so before July, and so will I still be able to release the app and the people I have talked to who have older devices can download it?

After doing some reading, it seems like you can set the Deployment Target lower than the 'Base SDK'. Is this true? How would this work if iOS 11 can do things that iOS 9 can't do?

I am therefore asking for clarification and answers to the 2 questions above.

Comment: You should still be able to set iOS9 as a build target in the iOS11 SDK.

Comment: What will this mean for iOS 9 users - will some features not work?

Comment: Sure, if they're not supported in that OS. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I answered it in another topic. You can check from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823995/error-when-trying-to-upload-xcode-project-please-update-xcode-and-rebuild-your/52674651#52674651

Comment: You can check the answer in the other topic from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823995/error-when-trying-to-upload-xcode-project-please-update-xcode-and-rebuild-your/52674651#52674651

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message means that your app must be built with a Base SDK of iOS 11. And this means you need to be using Xcode 9. It's always best to use the latest tools. Apple is always pushing developers forward.

But this does not prevent your app from supporting older iOS devices. If you wish to support back to iOS 9, set your project's or target's Deployment Target to iOS 9.0 (or whatever older version you wish to support).

The Deployment Target defines the oldest version of iOS your app supports. The Base SDK defines the latest APIs you can use.

The trick is to ensure that if you use a newer API in your app, it must not be used when the app is run on a device with an older version of iOS.

There are plenty of discussions that cover the details of this but in short, use `#available` around any API added after whatever Deployment Target you have set.

Update as of July 5, 2018:

According to the [Supported Xcode and Application Loader versions](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb1c185036) help page, Xcode 9 is only required for **new** iOS apps and iOS app extensions.

Comment: What about the older application that is target to older version.Will they remains in appstore or not?

Comment: @Niroj Apps that are not updated will remain in the App Store. But certainly your customers will be a lot happier if you update your app to take advantage of the newer devices.